# Sliding down a div and hiding it, as if it does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was trying to slide down this ".preloader" div down, after time interval of 2 seconds, and tried JQUERY, but I couldn't figure out why it was not working. Also, I didn't want to have a toggle button. I tried to create an animation with @keyframes, but as soon as the div goes out of the boundaries of the page, a scrollbar is shown, which you could use to scroll down and see that actually the div is placed underneath the html page. `

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-image: url('background_image_one.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}



.container {
  
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  border: white;
  border-style: solid;
  min-height: 60vh;
  width: 35rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0rem 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.avatar {
  min-height: 35vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.avatarimg {
  width: 40rem;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}


.info h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
.info h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  color: #585858;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}
.sizes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.sizes button {
  /* padding: 0.5rem 2rem; */
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0rem ;
  background: #f54642;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 1rem;
  
}
button.active {
  background: #585858;
  color: white;
}
.purchase {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}


/* тука са моите бутони */
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.forminput p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.forminput {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.preloader {
  background: #000823 url("bold-preloader.gif") no-repeat center center; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: slide 4s ease-out forwards;
  
}

@keyframes slide{
  0% {}
  
  50%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
    overflow: hidden;}
    
  100%{
    transform: translateY(100vh);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3d Card Effect</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
    <div class="preloader">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="avatar">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <img src="./userAvatar.png" alt="avatarimg" class="avatarimg">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h1 class="title">Log In</h1>
                
                <div class="forminput">
                    <p>Email:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sizes">
                    <button>Login</button>
                    
                    <button>Register</button>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see on the snippet, when the div is sliding down, it creates space underneath the main part of the body.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have the overflow on the wrong element. Probably needs to be on the body or container.

Comment: Yes, this trick did it. I changed the body's overflow-y to hidden and it worked brilliantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of translating the element, which means it still has height so you get a scroll bar as it disappears downwards, you could scale to 0 in the Y direction, having changed the transform-origin of the Y to the bottom of the page:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-image: url('background_image_one.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}



.container {
  
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  border: white;
  border-style: solid;
  min-height: 60vh;
  width: 35rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0rem 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.avatar {
  min-height: 35vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.avatarimg {
  width: 40rem;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}


.info h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
.info h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  color: #585858;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}
.sizes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.sizes button {
  /* padding: 0.5rem 2rem; */
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0rem ;
  background: #f54642;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 1rem;
  
}
button.active {
  background: #585858;
  color: white;
}
.purchase {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}


/* тука са моите бутони */
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.forminput p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.forminput {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.preloader {
  background: #000823 url("bold-preloader.gif") no-repeat center center; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: slide 4s ease-out forwards;
  
}

@keyframes slide{
  0% {}
  
  50%{
    transform: scaleY(1);
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    
  100%{
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: 0 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3d Card Effect</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
    <div class="preloader">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="avatar">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <img src="./userAvatar.png" alt="avatarimg" class="avatarimg">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h1 class="title">Log In</h1>
                
                <div class="forminput">
                    <p>Email:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sizes">
                    <button>Login</button>
                    
                    <button>Register</button>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @A Haworth, maybe it would work just find if I did not have anything in the div, which is animating. Unfortunately, I have a preloader.gif, which actually shrinks, whenever the animation is active.